# PC with 2 subnets and 2 different NICs

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

In my office, I have one computer connected to two subnets via two network cards (NICs).

- NIC 1: `192.168.0.151/24` Gateway: `192.168.0.1`
- NIC 2: `10.60.33.109/24`  Gateway: (blank)

I would like to connect from my PC at IP `10.60.33.10/24` to the computer service when typing `192.168.0.151` into the IE web browser. How can I achieve this?

I am very new to networking. Please let me know the steps.

Comment: I find this question to be very unclear.  If Spiff’s answer isn’t what you want, you should really [edit] this question to be clearer and provide more details.   For example, I guess you’re talking about two computers, but you don’t actually say so.   And what do you mean by “the computer service”?   If you want any sort of step-by-step instructions, you’ll have to tell what operating system(s) your machine(s) are using (although the reference to “IE” suggests that the second machine is running some form of Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your client PC at 10.60.33.10 and set its default gateway to 10.60.33.109. That way it'll try to send all off-subnet traffic to the local NIC of your 2-NIC machine, and your 2-NIC machine will probably recognise the traffic to 192.168.0.151 as being destined to itself (this is called the "'weak' end-system model"), so it should accept it and reply to it.

Of course, if 10.60.33.0/24 was a real subnet with a real gateway, this might not be the right solution for you. But if that's the case, you need to give us a lot more information about how your network is set up so we don't have to sit here and guess about how these subnets may or may not be connected to the Internet or each other.